# u_char (*)[10] & char (*)[10] format specifiers in C

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I have to correct an existing C file which has a bunch of format specifiers compilation errors.
Can anyone tell the correct format specifiers for the following cases:

1. `u_char(*) [10]` (I tried %s, but didn't work)
2. `char(*) [10]` (I tried %s and %c, but didn't work)

Thanks.

Comment: Try `%p`, that works for all pointers.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov: Not at all: `%p` *only* works for `void *` (or CV-qualified versions thereof), all else is UB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are pointers to arrays, so you can dereference them to become arrays, which decay to pointers-to-first-element:

```
char arr[10];

char (*pa)[10] = &arr;
printf("%s", *pa);   // or &((*pa)[0])
```

To spell it out: the type of `pa` is `char(*)[10]`, and the type of `*pa` is `char[10]`, and the latter decays to a `char*` of value `&((*pa)[0])` (equal to `&(arr[0])`).

Comment: Why couldn't you just do `printf("%s", &arr[0])`? Isn't `char arr[10]` technically a pointer too?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: You could, or you could just say `printf("%s", arr);`, but that has nothing to do with the original question. `arr` is just here for exposition, and to give `pa` a meaningful value.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kerrek, but I think

```
printf ("%s", *pa);
```

may not work as is since we are not sure if there is a NULL character at the end. So to print we can do the following

```
char temp[10+1];
memcpy(temp, *pa, 10);
temp[10] = '\0';
printf("%s",temp);
```

Comment: If you're worried about non-null-terminated data, wasteful copies are not the solution. `printf` has precision specifiers for a reason. Use `printf("%.10s", *pa);`